# How do I use Architecture Components with MediaBrowserService?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-architecture-components, mediabrowserservice

I'm trying to make an app that plays audio with the MediaBrowserService but also use the new Architecture Components to structure the whole app. I have use MediaBrowserService before for another app(https://github.com/willhwongwork/PodCast) but in that app I did not use the OnGetRoot() and OnGetChildren() methods to load the data I just load data using loader or asynctask from network(and there's no architecture in that app).

So now if I want to use LiveData and ViewModel how should I structure the code? Should I use them in the MediaBrowserService and through the OnGetRoot() and OnGetChildren() methods provide the data to the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `AppCompatActivity` or support `Fragment` which are `LifecycleOwner` due to which we can use `ViewModelProviders` and `observe` of `LiveData`, the `Service` doesn't implement the `LifecycleOwner` interface.

That said, there is [LifecycleService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleService.html) which implements the `LifecycleOwner` interface. 
I don't think the `MediaBrowserService` implements the `LifecycleOwner` hence you'll need to use [ServiceLifecycleDispatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ServiceLifecycleDispatcher.html) and create a custom `MediaBrowserService`.

Note: Kindly also take a look at what Florina says about Service with Lifecycle: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/137

Answer (score 0):

You can use onLoadChildren() method to load chunks of data, using the new [Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/), which is part of the Android Architecture Components. I wrote a [post](https://medium.com/@shevach/how-to-paginate-mediabrowserservice-e4fdc902ff2) about it where I use a cursor to fetch MediaItems from the MediaStore, but the same can be done with LiveData as well